# SharpSVN - Is there anyway to be notified of pending updates?

Tags: c#, .net, sharpsvn

Is there any to be notified of pending updates (on the server) or do I need to poll for changes?

Ideally I don't want to poll, as this is inefficient waste of resources, both on the server and client.

Comment: What are pending updates in your mind?

Comment: I mean if someone else has committed changes to a branch, is there anyway for the server to notify interested clients

Comment: Use a post-commit hook in SVN.

Comment: would that require a change to the SVN server configuration, if so that's not possible...

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way for a server to contact individual clients... There are some standardized hooks. Google for `svnpubsub`.

A client really has to poll to know. `svn status -u` (SvnClient.Status(.., new SvnStatusArgs{RetrieveRemote=true},..) is the most efficient way to identify what incoming changes to expect. But the most efficient way to see if there are any changes would be to just obtain the last revision on the server using `svn info URL` (SvnClient.Info()).